# Auto-fill matrix without row-repetitions

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I have a series of numbers:

```
test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5]
```

which I want to randomely fill into a 3x5 matrix without having the same number in the same row.

How can I do this in matlab? Potentially I could randomize the test vector and fill it into the 5x3 matrix but I don't know how to do this without getting the same number in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill a 3-by-5 matrix with all of the values in `test`, making sure each row has no repeated values, you can do this very succinctly by using [`toeplitz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) to first generate an index matrix, then randomly permute the dimensions with [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html):

```
index = toeplitz(1:3, [3 5:-1:2]);
index = index(randperm(3), randperm(5));
```

And a sample `index`:

```
index =

     1     5     4     2     3
     4     3     2     5     1
     5     4     3     1     2
```

If your values in `test` are the numbers 1 through 5, this should be all you need to do. If `test` could be any vector with with 5 different numbers, three of each, then you can get the [unique](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) values of your `test` vector and index them with `index`. This solution will generalize to any `test` vector:

```
test = [3 3 3 7 7 7 5 5 5 9 9 9 4 4 4];    % Sample data
uniqueValues = unique(test);               % Get the unique values [3 4 5 7 9]
M = uniqueValues(index);                   % Use index as generated above
```

And the result will be guaranteed to be a reordered version of what's in `test`:

```
M =

     3     9     7     4     5
     7     5     4     9     3
     9     7     5     3     4
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. However I made a minor mistake. I want the final matrix to be a 3x5 and not a 5x3 as i wrote in the first place. Sorry for the mistake. Can you help med with this small change?

Comment: Awesome, thanks gnovice.I have one final question for you which I hope you can help me with. Say test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3] and I want to fill it into a 3x5 matix without row repetionen, and leave excess cells blank (or =) how is this done?

Comment: @J.Birch: I'm not clear on your requirements. If you only have 9 values in `test`, you can't ensure that no value is repeated in each row of 5, as required in your question. Do you just want each row to be unique from other every other row?

Comment: So here is what I am looking for: I have the sequence of numbers in the 1D "test" vector, for instance test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3] which I want to fill randomely into a 3x5 matrix even thoung I only have 9 numbers in the test vector. I want to fill the 3x5 matrix so I dont have any of the values repeated in the same row (except for 0 or nan) and fill in all the empty spaces with 0 or nan. Do I make sence?

Comment: Hi Gnovice. I really appreciate you explanation in the above answer, and I am sorry I made the mistakes in explaining the problem in a good. I have made a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371149/fill-matrix-randomly-without-row-repetitions) and hope you will have the time to help me once again. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force way of doing it

```
% data
test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5];

% randomly permute the indices
indices = randperm(numel(test));

% create a random matrix
matrix = reshape(test(indices), 5, 3);

% while number of unique elements in any of the rows is other than 3
while any(arrayfun(@(x) numel(unique(matrix(x,:))), (1:size(matrix,1)).')~=3)
    % keep generating random matrices
    indices = randperm(numel(test));
    matrix = reshape(test(indices), 5, 3);   
end;

% here is the result
result=matrix;
```

**EDIT :** If you want 3x5 like you mentioned in your comment, it is a lot easier. Just one line below.

```
[~, result] = sort(rand(3,5),2);
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. However I made a minor mistake. I want the final matrix to be a 3x5 and not a 5x3 as i wrote in the first place. Sorry for the mistake. Can you help med with this small change?

Comment: it is a lot easier if you want `3x5`: `[~, result] = sort(rand(3,5),2);`

Comment: Awesome, thanks Vahe.I have one final question for you which I hope you can help me with. Say test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3] and I want to fill it into a 3x5 matix without row repetionen, and leave excess cells blank (or =) how is this done?

Comment: you could add this afterwards, if I understand correctly what you want `result(ismember(result, [4,5]))=0;`

Answer (score 0):

You can take the *unique* matrix of *test* and pick any three elements out of it and fill in the required 5X3 matrix.

```
test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5] ;
test_unique = unique(test) ;
A = zeros(5,3) ;
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    A(i,:) = randsample(test_unique,3) ;
end
```

*randsample* needs a statistics toolbox, if you doesn't have it, you may use *randperm* as shown below.

```
test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5] ;
test_unique = unique(test) ;

A = zeros(5,3) ;
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    A(i,:) = test_unique(randperm(length(test_unique),3)) ;
end
```

If you want 3X5 matrix:

```
test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5] ;
test_unique = unique(test) ;
A = zeros(3,5) ;
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    A(i,:) = randsample(test_unique,5) ;
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. However I made a minor mistake. I want the final matrix to be a 3x5 and not a 5x3 as i wrote in the first place. Sorry for the mistake. Can you help med with this small change?

Comment: Code edited...it would be a minor change....you could have done it easily.