# Fill matrix randomly without row-repetitions

Tags: matrix, random

Please help. I'm new to matlab scripting and need a bit of help. I have a series of numbers:

A=[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5]

which I want to fill randomly into an 8x12 matrix without having the same number in the same row. At the end I want all the "empty" cells of the 8x12 matrix being filled with 0's or nan.

an example could be:

result=

3 1 5 2 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0

4 1 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 3 4 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Does the first one count as a different number than the second one?

Comment: Sorry Thijs, but I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: "without having the same number in the same row" is the row 1 0 1 ... a valid row?

Comment: can you perhaps provide an example matrix?

Comment: Ok now I get it. 1 0 1 is not a valid row. If one of the numbers appear in a row it may not appear again in the same row at all.

Comment: an example could be:                                                                                         result=[3 1 5 2 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0; 4 1 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 1 3 4 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]. I hope it makes sense?

Comment: @J.Birch: There are two fives in the first row of the example. Is this a typo?

Comment: @J.Birch: Some other issues: Your example is 3-by-12, should the remaining 5 rows be all 0? Also, does each row need to be different than every other row?

Comment: Hi gnovice. Great to see you here. Yes it is a typo, the second 5 is of cause not allowed. Yes the rest of the matrix should be 0's or nan's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-fill matrix without row-repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357871/auto-fill-matrix-without-row-repetitions)

Answer (score 0):

- make sure A is sorted. `A = sort(A)`[more info](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)
- make an empty matrix.
- For each number in A: [more info](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html)

  - find out how many repetitions of the number there are -> for loop in A, start is the first occurance of the number, end is the last, n = last-first+1
  - find all rows that have space for an extra number, just do a double for loop and keep track of elements that are zero
  - randomly pick n rows -> [more info](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html). To do this, make an array R of all available row indixes. Then take a random sample between 1..size(R,2) with the provided function and get all the values, you now have your row indixes.
  - randomly pick one of the empty spots in each of the selected rows and assign the number

Comment: Hi Thijs. It makes sense but I am totally new in matlab programming and therefore need help with the programming the solution to the problem.